# adding a div element via jQuery

Tags: jquery

In a complex loop that is getting data from Facebook I have to add a blank div with class name out side of an img tag.How do I do that.

```
//Currently it's like the following
<img src="img" id="imageID"></img>

//Need to get it to following using jQuery
<div class="className"> <img src="img" id="imageID"></img> </div>

//Script

$(#imageID).prepend("<div">).addClass("className").append(</div>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wrap the ID-Selector into string literals and should use [`$.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$('#imageID').wrap('<div class="className">');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TimWolla/68L7d/

Comment: Hi David,Thank for the answer but when I use the same concept to my project it's not working properly. The project can viewed at http://jsbin.com/adirus/9/edit 
Thanks in advance.